# Emacs blocked by interactive query in inaccessible frame

Tags: org-mode, frames, focus

Recently I found my emacs, which I run as a daemon, in a blocked state.

It would not react to any command. Not <kbd>C-g</kbd>, not cursor movements, nothing that I could think of. Then I realized, that I had opened another frame via mosh from my laptop, yesterday evening, and in that frame I had opened `org-agenda`.

After waking up the laptop, I saw that emacs was asking me whether I had really intended to leave a task in clocked-in state for such a long time. It was waiting for a keypress in the minibuffer.

Now, is it possible to move that question to the currently active frame, or to interrupt it within emacs?